# Theorem about the liminf and limsup

Tags: measure-theory

> Its apparently referred to as Besicovich theorem (I checked all of his available papers but they only one that seems relevant is related to Hausdorf measure and the set E is in the plane) : for $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E)>0$ and $m(E^c)>0$, there exists an  $ x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{1}{4}\leq \liminf \frac{m([x-r,x+r]\cap E)}{2r} \leq \limsup \frac{m([x-r,x+r]\cap E)}{2r} \leq \frac{3}{4}$$

What would be the steps or the literature needed to prove this general result. Because it seems true for every type of set $E$ I tried, but proving this seems highly nontrivial.

Edit: I tried a bunch of things. First i realized that this point has to be on the boundary, as by the Lebesgue density theorem, for a.e x the density is $1$ on the interior, and $0$ on the exterior.

Another thing that i tried doing is i noticed that $m[x-r, x+r]\cap E]=\int_{[x-r,x+r]} \mathbb{1}_E$ but i couldnt follow up with anything definite.